# RAMDirectory Lucene

Tags: java, text, lucene, indexing, ramdirectory

I am trying to index text files and using the RAMDirectory for fast indexing and was wondering if there is a way to clear the previous RAMDirectory to prevent duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "clear the previous RAMDirectory", but you can overwrite the previous index at the RAMDir by string the create flag to true. This would create a new index at the location for the constructor call.

```
IndexWriter(Directory d, Analyzer a, boolean create, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength mfl)
```

> [Constructs an IndexWriter for the index in d.](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html)

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I just forgot to close the IndexWriter.